# listen to object property changes inside array in a service

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, observable

So basically what I want to achieve is `watching/listening` `objects` changing inside of `array` within an `injectable` `service` using `setters` and `getters` to manipulate it's data

eg

```
@Injectable()
export class StorageService {
    protected items: Array<any> = [];

    constructor(private storage: Storage) {
        this.storage.ready().then(() => {
            StorageService.getGetters().forEach((get) => {
                this.storage.get(get).then(res => this.items[get] = res);
            });
        });
    }

    public static getGetters(): string[] {
        return Object.keys(this.prototype).filter(name => {
            return typeof Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this.prototype, name)["get"] === "function"
        });
    }

    get Storage() {
        return this.storage;
    };

    ClearStorage() {
        this.storage.clear();
    }

    protected Setter(key: string, value: any): void {
        this.items[key] = value;
        this.storage.set(key, value);
    }

    protected Getter(key: string): any {
        return this.items[key];
    }

    set User(value: User) {
        this.Setter('User', value);
    }

    get User(): User {
        return this.Getter('User');
    }

}
```

where `User` `interface` is :

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    role_id: number;
    name: string;
    email?: string;
}
```

now in any `component` or `service/provider` I can `DI` my `StorageService` so I can access the `User` `getter`.

so:

```
storage.User.name = 'testing';
```

now the `name` is changed , but I have no way to track that , so I can update my storage!

to update my `storage` I would do:

```
    storage.User.name = 'testing';
    storage.User = storage.User;
```

which is working , but I need a way to listen to any changes happens to the `object` `properties`, so I can update my storage...

I searched alot , and all I can find is `watching` `components` `@Input()` , which is not working in my case.

Hopefully I made my point clear.

Comment: use Subject here

Comment: @Sajeetharan an example code would be appreciated, but I will look into it

Comment: @Abanoub use shared services and Subject i:e a observable as sanjeetharan pointed . [link](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)